# Windows-like online file managment

Tags: laravel, file-management

I want to make a page on a website where a user can manage files. Download, upload, change name and drag to another directory.

Like the folders work in windows, but online. Is there something out there that can do this?

I am working in Laravel btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of jQuery plugin available for File management.

Here we go,

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-file-manager-plugins/

You can create your own too... using ajax and jQuery